# How to start a console app from powershell in a new window

Tags: powershell

My team develops a website of which each developer has a local copy running in full IIS.  We also have a service that in production runs in Azure, but for development we have it wrapped in a Console app.  If the developer needs this service, he starts the Console app either by double clicking the exe, running a batch or having the exe pinned to his Windows Task Bar.  This opens a console window on his Desktop and stays running until he chooses to shut it down.

I am writing a powershell script that the developer can run to update the many parts of our application on a regular basis.

Of course, if this service is running in the Console App, it has files locked.  So I have written as a part of this script to check for the Console app and stop it (which works).

However, I want to restart it.  But simply calling the exe (& MyService.exe) starts the app within the context of the powershell window and blocks the session.

How can I cause the exe to come up in it's own Windows Console window?

```
if (Get-Process | ? { $_.Name -eq "SchedulerConsole" }) {
    $schedulerwasrunning = $true
    Write-Host "shutting down SchedulerConsole" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Stop-Process -Name SchedulerConsole
}
```

...

```
if ($schedulerwasrunning) {
    Write-Host "restarting SchedulerConsole" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    & "$workspaceroot\blah\blah\SchedulerConsole.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Start-Process` rather than the `&` operator. This will spawn the application in a new console window.

Comment: accepting this answer because it seems more natural in PowerShell